# Array always returns its first value when using number_format with value taken from a function's output

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a function that gets the total number of posts in subcategories of a given WordPress category:

```
function wp_get_cat_postcount($id) {
    $cat = get_category($id);
    $count = (int) $cat->count;
    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $args = array('child_of' => $id);
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $count +=$tax_term->count;
    }
    return $count;

$items_cnt = wp_get_cat_postcount(CATEGORY_ID);
```

Then I'm using the following well known snippet to add the correct word form after a number:

```
function items_total($items_cnt, $items_total)
{
    $items = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $items_cnt." ".$items_total[
        ($items_cnt%100 > 4 && $items_cnt %100 < 20) ? 2 : 
        $items[min($items_cnt%10, 5)] ];
}

$items_num_plus_word = items_total($items_cnt,array('item', 'items', 'items'));

echo $items_num_plus_word;
```

Everything works great until I want to add some formatting to the outputted number, like `items_total(number_format($items_cnt, 0, ',', '.'),array('item', 'items', 'items'))`, after that the array always returns its first value so I have `5 item` instead of `5 items`.

What's wrong?

Comment: Where and how do you use `number_format()` in your code?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/94UgL

Comment: I'm using it in `items_total(number_format($items_cnt, 0, ',', '.'),array('item', 'items', 'items'))`. Did you enter the number directly or take it from a variable? I have added a paragraph to my question a minute ago that describes this strange behavior when it works properly with directly entered number and doesn't work with a number taken from a variable.

Comment: See the link in the above comment I executed the exact code you provided in the question and it works fine.

Comment: Is seems I should expand my question with one more snippet. The variable gets the number from the function. You are absolutely right, the snippet itself is working. But it makes my problem even more complicated :)

Comment: you might want to read [mcve].

Comment: I've red that, but I can operate with PHP only by using pre-coded snippets, I'm just learning. And sometimes it is impossible for me to catch the faulty piece of code. I'm very sorry.

Comment: If we can't reproduce your error we can't help you.

Comment: What is the exact output when you do: `var_dump($items_cnt);` right before the function call?

Comment: It is `int(1213)`. 1213 is the number of posts, that's correct.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure if you did this intentionally or unintentionally, but what is happening is that you use `,` as decimal separator and `.` as thousands separator in your `number_format()` call. Now normally it is exactly the opposite, or at least for english and american people and maybe a few more, so `.` is the decimal separator and `,` is the thousands separator. What that now means is that you basically formatted `1213` as it was `1.213` which then in the function itself when it is used as integer is equal to just `1` so for the number 1 it returns `item` instead of `items`.

Comment: I've made it intentionally. But how it could explain that directly entered value formats correctly and doesn't crush the array? Additionally I've tried to reproduce all the examples from [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) with the same result, even with comma.

Comment: Did you use the same value as the function returned, so `1213`? Because if you used `999999` then it is a different number. Otherwise it won't work either: https://3v4l.org/h276a

Comment: I've used different values from 1 to 35 :). I'm afraid it doesn't matter how am I going to format my number output, the function either thinks it deals with 1 or ruins the array. I don't know (. I've devided my "5 items" into two parts by adding number_formatted `$items_cnt` before `$items_num_plus_word` output with `strstr` applied. I'm sure there is more elegant way rather than that crutch but I'm not ready for such buttle right now. :) Anyway, it was you who helped me to understand that my original idea was faulty, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Not exactly sure, but you probably can just pass the plain number to the function and only format it for the output. So place your `number_format()` call here: ` return number_format($items_cnt, 0, ",", ".") . " " . ...`

Comment: Hm... I thought I've tried to apply `number_format` to all `$items_cnt`s found in code but it seems I've just skipped this exact one. May be 6am was the reason. :) **It works**, thank you once again! Could you please repost your solution as the answer, so that I could mark and rate it?